# Defining an async function type in Rust

Tags: types, rust

If I want to define a type that represents a function, I can write:

```rust
type FS = fn(i32) -> i32;
```

How do I define an async function though?

```rust
type FA = async fn(i32) -> i32; // invalid syntax
type FA = fn(i32) -> impl Future<i32>; // unstable and not allowed
type FA<R> = fn(i32) -> R where R impl Future<i32>; // invalid syntax
```

Also, how would I do this if I wanted to use the `Fn` / `FnMut` / `FnOnce` traits?

Comment: Note that `fn()` represents a function **pointer**. The recommended way to use higher-order functions is to use the `Fn`/`FnMut`/`FnOnce` traits. These are implemented for **closures** that can capture local variables of the containing function. Using the `Fn*` traits is also more efficient, because they can be inlined.

Comment: @Aloso, sounds good. Can you please post an example of how to do that (or a link to the relevant documentation)? Do I create a type `trait FA<R>: Fn(i32) -> R where R: std::future::Future<Output = i32> {}`? Maybe something else? And how do I use it?

Comment: Trait aliases are unstable. I'd just use `impl Trait` directly, e.g. `fn foo<F>(f: impl Fn(i32) -> F)
where
    F: Future<Output = i32>,
{...}`

Comment: Have you tried the feature [`type_alias_impl_trait`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/63063) for the 2nd example ? (`type FA = fn(i32) -> impl Future<i32>;`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct syntax is

```
type FA<R: Future<Output = i32>> = fn(i32) -> R;
```

However, the compiler warns that bounds on type aliases aren't enforced, so we can omit it:

```
type FA<R> = fn(i32) -> R;
```

Then we can use it like this ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2f0af9dfdff838171d7c66558799c3fb)):

```
fn foo(f: FA<impl Future<Output = i32>>) {
    let _ = f(7);
}
```